# Cross Origin Issue: sending XML POST to localhost

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I am new to jquery and javascript.

I have a server listening at localhost:8080. I am trying to make a login page that sends username and password.

```
function check_log(form)/*function to check userid & password*/
{
    $.post("localhost:8080",
    {
        username: form.username.value,
        submit: "Login"
    },
    function (data, status){
        // Do things
    });
}
```

The error message is, "cross origin requests are only supported for http". My url is file:///Users/.../login.html. I understand that this is wrong according to the origin policy, but how do I correctly do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Put this page on the server, or use jsonp.

Comment: How do I put the page on the server? Sorry I'm new.

Comment: "I have a server listening at localhost:8080" -- What server are you using, what operating system?

Comment: httpd = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(
            ('localhost', AUTH_SERVER_PORT), CustomHandler)
        httpd.serve_forever()

Comment: Your CustomHandler should have a line like `if self.path=="/": self.path="/index.html"`.  You just stick you index.html in wherever it is looking, and then visit localhost:8080 in your browser.

Comment: I tried this:

class CustomHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def __init__(self):
        if self.path=="/": 
            self.path="/index.html"

And it still does not work